# Show modal once per session in React

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to show a popup modal once per user session and I was wondering how I can incorporate jquery cookies in my React app so that the website knows when the user has returned and will not display the modal again until the user's cookie data has been cleared. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Modal = ({ showModal, setShowModal }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {showModal ? (
        <Wrap>
          <TopWrap>
            <h1>IMPORTANT</h1>
            <Close onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>Close</Close>
          </TopWrap>
          <h3 style={{ fontWeight: "200" }}>
            text here
          </h3>
        </Wrap>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

const Wrap = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  bottom: 2%;
  right: 2%;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 20px;
`;

const TopWrap = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

const Close = styled.h4`
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  &:hover {
    color: black;
  }
`;
export default Modal;
```

I am using React hooks so that when the user pressed the 'close' text it closes the modal. The issue I am trying to solve is that the modal appears every time I refresh the page and I would like to only display it once per session. I know it is possible to do this in HTML with JQuery but I am not sure how I can implement that in React.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a cookie that expires once the user closes the browser session.

```
document.cookie = "showedModal=showedModal; path=/";
```

In your code you only have to check if the cookie exists. If it does, show the modal and if not, dont show it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const useSessionModal = ()=> {
    const session = useSession();
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    const hideModal = ()=>{
        const modalKey = "modalSession";
        localStorage.setItem(modalKey, session);
        setShowModal(false);
    }
    useEffect(()=> {
        const modalKey = "modalSession";
        const modalSession = localStorage.getItem(modalKey);
        setShowModal(modalSession!==session);
    });
    return [showModal, hideModal];
}

const Modal = () => {
    const [showModal, hideModal] = useSessionModal();
  return (
    <>
      {showModal ? (
        <Wrap>
          <TopWrap>
            <h1>IMPORTANT</h1>
            <Close onClick={hideModal}>Close</Close>
          </TopWrap>
          <h3 style={{ fontWeight: "200" }}>
            text here
          </h3>
        </Wrap>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

Save session related tag in localStorage;

Comment: The modal doesn't disappear when I click 'close', I have properly implemented hidemodal to the onClick component like you did above

Comment: @ron10052 check onClick is triggered normally.https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-river-cf8su, this is my testcode

Answer (score -1):

No yow bro, you don’t need no jquery, cookies or none of that. All you need is sessionStorage, sessionStorage is the same as localStorage, but with one difference, what ever you store there will be deleted as soon as you close the tap.

### First

when you app loads check your sessionStorage

const openend = typeof sessionStorage.getItem(“opened”) === “string”

if the answer is no, then open the modal if the answer is yes then don t open

if (openend===false) {

// open modal

}

### Second

When your modal is close set the openend

sessionStorage.setItem(“opened”,”1”);